# How to uninstall java on a windows server using bat file?

Tags: java, windows, batch-file

We are developing a project which needs us connect to the server remotely and to install and uninstall java in the server. We've tried the following in vain:

```
wmic product where "name like 'Java™%%%'" call uninstall  
wmic product where "name = 'java 7 update 1'" uninstall /nointeractive
wmic product where "name = 'java 7 update 2'" call uninstall /nointeractive  
wmic product where "name = 'java 7 update 3'" call uninstall /nointeractive 
wmic product where "name = 'java 7 update 4'" call uninstall /nointeractive
```

Please let me know how to uninstall java from the server using a bat file command.

Comment: On a machine installed with it and in a cmd window, what is the output of `WMIC Product Where "Name Like 'Java%'" Get`?

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible to uninstall java from a Windows PC, without using a 3rd party utility or firing up WMIC. I suggest you look into 3rd party utilites